# Keyword 'this' in jquery, when is inside a function, how could change the scope?

Tags: jquery, scope, this, parent, point

If i write:

```
$('.myDiv').live('click',function(){
    $(this).find('.mySubDiv').each(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

I would like that the second 'this' point to .myDiv and not to .mySubDiv

There is some method where i write `$(this.parent)` or something similar, without save `$('.myDiv')` inside a variable?

Comment: In your current code, what do you need the .each for? or are you doing more in the each

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this:

```
var el = $(this);
```

And then just use `el`

Answer (score 0):

`this` changes scope depending on which code block you're in (it does this because along with iterating or firing events jQuery also assigns scope depending on what called each function). However, you can "cache" the reference by saving it as a variable:

```
$('.myDiv').live('click',function(){
    var myDiv = $(this); // one example of caching `this`

    $(this).find('.mySubDiv').each(function() {
        var mySubDiv = $(this); // another example of caching `this`

        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

So now you have a reference to the specific instances of `.myDiv` or `.mySubDiv` based on where `$(this)` was referenced.